# document.referrer not working for live server in angular 9

Tags: angular, document

i am using angular 9 and my app has one form and this form hosted on third party website using
iframe. so i want third party url

i am using `document.referrer` but this work in local but when i upload on live this dose`t work

my iframe code is

```
<iframe src="https://mywebsite.com/form/2aa878sd-0811-11e8-b70f-42010a980sdfe" width="100%" height="800px"></iframe>
```

this is third party url

```
https://mywebsite.com/iframe/test.html?id=5&name=vivek
```

i wont to get id name from url in my app

Comment: Please refer to this document and set the policy in your iframe according to it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please set reference policy as referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade" in your Iframe.